# Uploading files to server - c#

Tags: c#, file-upload

I build a client server application for uploading file from a client folder to server. 
My server WebMethod for uploading follows -

```
[WebMethod]
public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
{
    // the byte array argument contains the content of the file
    // the string argument contains the name and extension
    // of the file passed in the byte array
    new general().logError("UploadFile " + fileName);
    try
    {
        // instance a memory stream and pass the
        // byte array to its constructor
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);

                   FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath
                    ("~/data/") + fileName, FileMode.Create);

        // write the memory stream containing the original
        // file as a byte array to the filestream
        ms.WriteTo(fs);

        // clean up
        ms.Close();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
        new general().logError("After saving the file");
        // return OK if we made it this far
        return "OK";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

The function that calls this WebMethod follows -

```
private void uploadIt(string fName)
    {
        FileStream f = File.OpenRead(fName);

        cloudius.cloudius m = new cloudius.cloudius();

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            f.CopyTo(ms);

            //string[] drive = fName.Split(':');
            string[] p = fName.Split('\\');

            string b = m.UploadFile(ms.ToArray(), p[p.Length - 1]); // 

        }
    }
```

When running the aboce code I get the following error -

**Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'.**

Any idea what is causing this error ?

Comment: do you also get an http 500 error code?

Comment: what happens when you step through this do you his your Exception and what does your stack trace say?

Comment: @S.Dav Yes, I can see now that I get **500 - Internal server error**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things after some research, it looks like it is a form of a error page coming back. Go have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490677/client-found-response-content-type-of-text-html-but-expected-text-xml) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115319/how-can-the-error-client-found-response-content-type-of-text-html-be-interp).

Hope this gives you some form of clarification on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy if the main purpose of your method is just to upload a file you can use :

```
FileUpload fu;  // Get the FileUpload object.
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("file.dat"))
{
    fu.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Flush();
}
```

That will be more efficient, as you will be directly streaming the input file to the destination host, without first caching in memory or on disk.

Comment: I need to upload folders tree from a Windows project. Not sure if it's possible to use FileUpload control for this purpose.